# How to handle dateTime with nanosecond precision in Mysql 5.7.x

Tags: mysql

I'm using Mysql 5.7.26 and I've a table with a column defined as a DATETIME(6). 
However in my application I'm using nanosecond precision. I'm saving all dates as UTC.

This query for example:

```
UPDATE subscription SET validUntil='2019-10-01 21:59:59.999999999' WHERE id=1
```

persist the date in Mysql as

```
2019-10-01 22:00:00.000000
```

I don't want this. Is there any setting to tell Mysql to truncate the fractional second after the sixth digit?

I'm usign SqlYog community edition to execute the query.

Comment: "MySQL 5.7 has fractional seconds support for TIME, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP values, with up to microseconds (6 digits) precision: ...", see [11.3.6 Fractional Seconds in Time Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html).

Comment: Thanks, I know that. The point is that I don't want Mysql do a "rouding" on my date during an INSERT/UPDATE if I'm using nanoseconds. Would make much more sense just truncate the digits that exceed...

Comment: "*The fsp value, if given, must be in the range 0 to 6*" - You cannot specify precision beyond 6 digits (microseconds). If you want to store upto nanoseconds; my suggestion is to store it in two separate columns, one storing datetime only; and another integer column storing nanoseconds values (bigint unsigned)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya It's ok to loose precision but I don't want a "rouding". In fact because I'm using UTC when Mysql do that, the date represented is the day after what I was originally saving.

Comment: @drenda Unfortunately, "*The temporal values are inserted into the table with rounding .. No warning or error is given when such rounding occurs. This behavior follows the SQL standard, and is not affected by the server sql_mode setting.*" So, we cannot control it through any settings.. Best option is to store fractional seconds separately as an integer.

Comment: Truncate the time inside your code?

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, it's what I'm doing right now. Not very confortable, but it works. Thanks

Comment: @drenda something like `SET validUntil = SUBSTRING('2019-10-01 21:59:59.999999999', 1, 26)`... that would use MySQL to do the truncating.